# What do the Misc. items do?

Tags: ridiculous-fishing

I've noticed that there are Miscelleneous items in the store in Ridiculous Fishing, but they don't really make it obvious what they do.

[image: A screenshot of the Shoppe Ship, with the Fishopedia selected. The description reads, "#2 Best fishing guide of 1996."]

So far I've seen a hat and a fish encyclopedia, but I assume that there are more. What do all these do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Misc." category contains items that simply did not fit in any other categories. Most of these are equippable, and *some* have effects. Most of the items in the category do have descriptive enough flavor text, but as you have noticed, not all do.

Following is a complete list of miscellaneous items in Ridiculous Fishing and their effects, in order of appearance in the shop - spoilers included, of course.

- **Cap** - Aesthetic, equippable as a hat. No effect.
- **Gnarkepi** - Aesthetic, equippable as a hat.
- **Jellmet** - Aesthetic, equippable as a hat.
- **Fishopedia** - Catalogues which fish you have caught so far, and how many of them.
- **Suit** - You earn 10% more for selling fish. Equippable as an outfit.
- **Wizard robe** - You earn 20% more for selling fish. Equippable as an outfit.
- **Emperor's Suit** - You earn 50% more for selling fish. Equippable as an outfit.
- **Paper Hat** - Aesthetic, equippable as a hat.
- **Pirate Hat** - Aesthetic, equippable as a hat.
- **Hunting Hat** - Aesthetic, equippable as a hat.
- **Frozen hat** - Possibly used to get certain fish - there is no record, it seems, of anyone getting one or two fish *without* the hat on, but nothing has been confirmed. Equippable as a hat.
- **Hedjet** - Used in the Home Waters in order to encounter five very rare fish. Without it, they don't appear. Equippable as a hat.
- **Cowboy Hat** - Aesthetic, equippable as a hat.
- **Top Hat** - Aesthetic, equippable as a hat. Adds a button to the fishing screen to pour money into it to make it grow taller.

Only one hat and one outfit can be worn at a time. If you try to equip a new one of either, the other of the same type will be automatically unequipped.